# Exploding with file.txt not bring anything

Tags: php, arrays, explode

hello can somebody help me..
i try to make explode while my file.txt

like this :

1. ujang
2. ahmad
   3, memet
3. cangak

and my syntax is like this

```
<?php 
error_reporting(0);
function gs($string, $start, $end){
    $string = ' ' . $string;
    $ini = strpos($string, $start);
    if ($ini == 0) return '';
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string, $end, $ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string, $ini, $len);
}
$isi = readline('List_Name.txt');
$s = file_get_contents($isi);
$sd = explode('#--------------------------[ NEW SCAMA ]-----------------------------#', $s);
$key = array ();
foreach ($sd as $key) {
    if($key !== ''){
        $name = gs($key, 'names     : ', "\n");
        file_put_contents("Hasil.txt", $name."|"."\n", FILE_APPEND);
    }
}
?>
```

but it wont bring up anything,, can help me please

Comment: Comment out `file_put_contents` and do some debugging. Does `$name` ever evaluate to  anything useful? Because this line will return the empty string `if ($ini == 0) return '';`. Does that happen everytime? ..... You have to debug your code or provide the input data. No one knows what your input data is to debug this.

Comment: `strpos()` returns `false` not `0` when the needle is not found, btw, as 0 is a valid index and points to the first char of the string. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php